# OnItemSelected Won't call when Spinner is getting arraylist from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, spinner

The app gets an array list from Firebase via `OnDataChange` and has `OnItemSelected`, but unfortunately it won't call. (Actually the spinner is getting the Strings from the Firebase database.)
I've tested the code with a local arraylist and `OnItemSelected` works.
Why?

These are my functions:

```
        public void initSpinner() {

        restartAudioSpinner();


        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddAudioItems.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categoriesTitle);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }




   public void restartAudioSpinner() {
        DatabaseReference database;
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Audio Categories");

        database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                categorylist = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (DataSnapshot data :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    CategoryNew category = data.getValue(CategoryNew.class);
                    categoriesList.add(new CategoryNew(category.getImageUrl(),category.getTitle()));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
                    categoriesTitle.add(categoriesList.get(i).getTitle());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(AddAudioItems.this, categoriesTitle.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        Toast.makeText(AddAudioItems.this, "לא נבחרה שום רשומה, אנא בחר קטגוריה", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: Is the spinner populated with the list of data? And you should not do `Thread.sleep(4000);` if thats on the main thead.

Comment: Yes, you can see the full code here: https://pastebin.com/hSH0dfuB

Comment: You are doing `Thead.sleep(4000);` on the main thread, you should instead wait for the data in the callback when it is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have found an answer myself.
Firebase functions works a-synchronically. I haven't found a way to change that - manipulate it somehow.
The answer of working with data that is received from a firebase function is to initialize the desired function AFTER the for (gathering the information form the database) INSIDE onDataChange.
for example:

```
   public void restartAudioSpinner() {
    DatabaseReference database;
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Audio Categories");

    database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            categorylist = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot data :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                CategoryNew category = data.getValue(CategoryNew.class);
                categoriesList.add(new CategoryNew(category.getImageUrl(),category.getTitle()));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
                categoriesTitle.add(categoriesList.get(i).getTitle());
            }
                 **// PUT THE DESIRED FUNCTION HERE!!!** EX: INIT THE SPINNER
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```